# Почему парсер не выводит ссылки?

Tags: python, парсер

Пытался по книге написать парсер, должен при выводе выдавать ссылки, но не делает этого.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, вставьте исходник и результат выполнения программы в тело вопроса

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке

```
if "html" in url:
```

наверное, всё-таки имелось в виду не `html`, а `http`.

Потому что ссылок, содержащих `html`, на той странице действительно нет, вот ничего и не выводится.